# Incrementing a database counter concurrently

Tags: python, django, postgresql, concurrency

From what I read in the PostgreSQL [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html), it seems that queries like

```
UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance + 100 WHERE account_id = 12345
```

are atomic and can be safely executed concurrently. Is this only the case when a single integer column is updated? In my Django app I have a query like this (generated by the ORM):

```
UPDATE "mytable" SET "counter" = ("mytable"."counter" + 1), 
  "owner" = NULL, "updated" = '2018-04-12T12:53:17.826257+00:00'::timestamptz
WHERE "mytable"."id" = 27; args=(1, datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 12, 12, 53, 17, 826257, tzinfo=<UTC>), 27)
```

which is executed concurrently by multiple background jobs. Will the counter be updated atomically in this case? I'm using the autocommit mode (Django default).

Comment: Counter will be updated atomically anyway, either in explicit or implicit transaction (autocommit).  Some info is here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-begin.htm

Comment: The question was more about whether the query would be executed concurrently by multiple background jobs **without race conditions**. It's not clear from the docs and other similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40162952/275088) on SE (they use statements that update a single column).

Answer (score 0):

What you might need is an F Expression: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions

From the docs: Another useful benefit of F() is that having the database - rather than Python - update a field’s value avoids a race condition.

```
from django.db.models import F
instance = MyModel.objects.get(pk=xxx)
instance.counter = F('instance.counter') + 1
instance.owner = null
instance.save()
```

Reload instance to get updated values from db.